# Problem with app layout for phones with different screen densities

Tags: android, android-layout, huawei-mobile-services, screen-density

I have problem with layout of my app for below phones . in first one layout looking good but in the second phone the layout not exactly like first one . 
though i put the xml files in (Layout-w480dp) folder and i do not use constraint layout

**huawei G8 :** 
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPb8V.png)
Resolution : 1920 x 1080 px
Screen Density : 403 ppi 
Screen Density (DPI) : 480 ppi (xxhdpi)
                       (640dp) x (360dp)

**huawei Y9 :** 
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OawXh.jpg)
Resolution : 2160 x 1080 px
Screen Density : 407 ppi 
Screen Density (DPI) : 480 ppi (xxhdpi)
                       (720dp) x (360dp)

thanks

Comment: can you add screen shot of both scenarios for better clarity?

Comment: are you using one xml file for both the resolutions?

Comment: @ankuranurag2 i uploaded them ...@Wijdan yes i have one xml file for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this attribute to your `textView` in xml `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`
this will resize the text size to fit the textview area

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"    
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

for further customizing you can set

```
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes"
```

where `autosize_text_sizes` is an array in arrays.xml values res file
 *create it by right click on values  -> new   -> values resource file -> name it arrays.xml*, which choose dynamically the text size based on text area availability

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<array name="autosize_text_sizes">
    <item>10sp</item>
    <item>50sp</item>
    <item>150sp</item>
</array>
```